# s3fs: how to force remount on errors?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, fuse, s3fs

I use [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) 1.33 on Ubuntu 9.10.

Regularily it gives me errors like this:

```
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to socket [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
rsync: close failed on "/mnt/s3/mybucket/filename": Software caused connection abort (103)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(731) [receiver=3.0.6]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (86 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Any attempt to work with mounted directory after that gives this error:

```
Transport endpoint is not connected
```

To get rid of this, I have to remount.

Is there a way to force a remount automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10 helped.

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious as to where your rsync errors are coming from. Do a "grep s3fs /var/log/syslog" or "grep s3fs /var/log/messages" to try to uncover internal error conditions.  You can report these as an issue at http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/list for potential help.  If these messages imply a connectivity issue, then there isn't much that can be done.

Comment: Unfortunately (or, rather, fortunately), after upgrade to 10.10 this issue does not appear anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Command to unmount:

```
% fusermount -u /s3
```

Command to mount:

```
% /usr/bin/s3fs -o allow_other bucketname /s3
```